# Check if record exist in association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the following associations in Rails:

Company has_many User through memberships

Then in Membership I have the following:

```
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :user
validates_uniqueness_of :company_id, scope: user_id
```

So, imagine that I have the following:

```
company = Company.create
```

And I have a method that adds users to companies, such as:

```
def add_user(user)
  users << user
end
```

How would I make sure that the user is not already related to the company, to avoid raising the validation exception?

Right now I am doing this `user << user unless users.include?(user)` but I am wondering if there is a more Rails way of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the proxy object which controls access to the association using an anonymous module to prevent duplicates:

```
class Company
  has_many :users, through: :memberships do
    def <<(*users)
      super(*users - proxy_association.owner.users)
    end
  end
end
```

You can read more about Active Record Association Extensions in the docs:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Association+extensions